# Error in my playframework project saying the class has location not matching its contents

Tags: java, scala, playframework

Hi I am very new to PlayFramework and I am doing a tutorial I found online in creating a bookstore. I keep getting a compilation error saying that the class has location not matching its contents.I have included my code below.

Book.java (A model class)

```
 package Models;

    import java.util.HashSet;
    import java.util.Set;

    public class Book {

        public Integer id;
        public String title;
        public double price;
        public String author;
        private static Set<Book> books;

        public Book(){

        }

        public Book(Integer id, String title, double price, String author) {
            this.id = id;
            this.title = title;
            this.price = price;
            this.author = author;
        }

        static {
            books=new HashSet<>();
            books.add(new Book(1,"C++",20,"Mehani"));
            books.add(new Book(2,"Java",30,"Anju"));
        }

        public static Set<Book> allBooks(){
            return books;
        }

        public static Book fineById(Integer id){
            for (Book book:books){
                if (id.equals(book.id)){
                    return book;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        public static void add(Book book){
            books.add(book);
        }

        public static boolean remove(Book book){
            return books.remove(book);
        }
    }
```

BookController

```
 package controllers;

    import Models.Book;
    import play.data.Form;
    import play.filters.cors.CORSFilter;
    import play.filters.csrf.CSRFFilter;
    import play.filters.headers.SecurityHeadersFilter;
    import play.mvc.Controller;
    import play.mvc.Result;
    import javax.inject.Inject;
    import play.data.FormFactory;
    import views.html.Books.*;


    import java.util.Set;

    public class BookController extends Controller {

        @Inject
        FormFactory formFactory;

        @Inject
        CSRFFilter csrfFilter;
        @Inject
        CORSFilter corsFilter;
        @Inject
        SecurityHeadersFilter secHeaders;
        //for all books
        public Result index(){
            Set<Book> books= Book.allBooks();
            return ok(index.render(books));
        }

        //to add a book
        public Result create(){
            Form<Book> bookForm=formFactory.form(Book.class);
            return ok(create.render(bookForm));
        }

        //to save a book

        public Result save(){
            Form<Book> bookForm= formFactory.form(Book.class).bindFromRequest();
            Book book = bookForm.get();
            Book.add(book);
            return redirect(routes.BookController.index());
        }

        public Result edit(Integer id){
            return TODO;
        }

        public Result update(){
            return TODO;
        }

        public Result destroy(Integer id){
            return TODO;
        }

        public Result show(Integer id){
            return TODO;
        }
    }
```

routes

```
 # Routes
    # This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
    # ~~~~

    # An example controller showing a sample home page
    GET     /                           controllers.HomeController.index




    GET     /books                            controllers.BookController.index()
    GET     /books/create                    controllers.BookController.create()
    GET     /books/:id                       controllers.BookController.show(id: Integer)
    GET     /books/edit/:id                  controllers.BookController.edit(id: Integer)

    +nocsrf
    POST    /books/edit                      controllers.BookController.update()
    +nocsrf
    POST    /books/create                      controllers.BookController.save()
    GET     /books/destroy/:id         controllers.BookController.destroy(id: Integer)
    # Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
    GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

This is my index.scala.html view. (The variables are in red and says cannot find symbol)

```
@import Models.Book

@(books : Set[Book])

<html>
    <head>
        <title>All books</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>All Books</h1>

        @for(book <- books){

            <a href="#">@book.title</a>
            <p>Price: @book.price</p>
            <p>Author: @book.author</p>
        }

    </body>
</html>
```

This is the compilation error I get.

```
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source and 1 Java source to J:\myfirstapp\target\scala-2.12\classes ...
[error] error while loading Book, class file 'J:\myfirstapp\target\scala-2.12\classes\models\Book.class' has location not matching its contents: contains class Book
[error] one error found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] application - 

! @7a4gfkgn9 - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->

play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException: Compilation error[error while loading Book, class file 'J:\myfirstapp\target\scala-2.12\classes\models\Book.class' has location not matching its contents: contains class Book]
    at play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException$.apply(PlayExceptions.scala:34)
    at play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException$.apply(PlayExceptions.scala:34)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.$anonfun$taskFailureHandler$1(PlayReload.scala:33)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.taskFailureHandler(PlayReload.scala:28)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.compileFailure(PlayReload.scala:24)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.$anonfun$compile$3(PlayReload.scala:51)
    at scala.util.Either$LeftProjection.map(Either.scala:573)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.compile(PlayReload.scala:51)
```

I got this after trying to implement the save().

Structure of the project

```
myfirstapp
.g8
.gradle
.idea
app
controllers
Modles
Book
views
Books
home
index.scala.html
main.scala.html
conf
gradle
logs
project
public
target
test
build.gradle
build.sbt
gradlew
gradlew.bat
myfirstapp.iml
```

How do I fix this compilation error?

Comment: Hi, could you please post your project structure?

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I just added it

Comment: Sorry @michelle97, but I need to see the proper project structure, I mean which file is contained in which directory. Given the project structure you posted seems that all this files are in the same directory (at the same level), and this make no sense, as the project would give you completely different errors. My guess is that your Book.java file is in the wrong folder as java need to have the package/class structure same as the project/file structure.

Answer (score 1):

My best bet is that you probably miss that unlike Windows, Java and Scala are case-sensitive. so the path `models\Book.class` does not match the package name `package Models;`. And actually in the Java/Scala world it is customary to name your packages in lower case. Try changing the code of Book.java  to `package models;`. This probably will fix the issue for you.